# Angular Firestore: Save table data to a new collection/document

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I have an app whereby I retrieve data from the users collection where clubId is the foreign key (for want of a better term).

The app gets a count of all users with each clubId and presents the info in an html table, showing the Club Name, how many users are associated to that club and a calculated field showing how much each club owes(depending on the number of users).

[image]

I am having trouble saving the table data to another firestore collection, revenueReports.

This is the code to retrieve the data for the table:

club-count-service.ts

```
  getClubCounts() {
    return this.firestore.collection<MyData>('users').get().pipe(
      map(snapshot => {
        const clubCounts: any = {};
        snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
          const clubId = doc.data().clubId;
          if (clubCounts[clubId]) {
            this.club = doc.data().club
            clubCounts[clubId]++;
          } else {
            clubCounts[clubId] = 1;
          }
        });
        const clubData: ClubData[] = [];
        Object.entries(clubCounts).forEach(([clubId, count]) => {
          this.firestore.doc(`clubs/${clubId}`).valueChanges().subscribe((club: any) => {
            clubData.push({ clubId, clubName: club.name, count });
          });
        });
        return clubData;
      }),
      takeUntil(this.dataReadySubject)
    );
  }
```

Then in the component:

```
clubCounts$: any;

  ngOnInit(): void {
   
    this.clubCounts$ = this.myDS.getClubCounts();
  }
```

And in the html:

```
          <table
            class="table rounded-3 border-dark table-light table-sm table-striped table-hover table-bordered caption-top animate shadow table-responsive">
            <thead class="table-dark">
              <tr>
                <th>Club Name</th>
                <th>Count</th>
                <th>Club Yearly</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr *ngFor="let club of clubCounts$ | async">
                <td>{{ club.clubName}}</td>
                <td>{{ club.count }}</td>
                <td>{{ club.count * 2 | currency}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

So the question is, how do i save this data to another collection and document?

I have tried this code:

```
  // Function to save the clubCounts data to Firestore
  saveClubCountsToFirestore(clubCounts: any) {
    const dateSaved = new Date(); // You can also use serverTimestamp() if needed

    // Create a document in the 'revenueReports' collection
    this.afs.collection('revenueReports').add({
      dateSaved,
      clubCounts, // Assuming 'clubCounts' contains your data fetched from 'getClubCounts()'
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log('ClubCounts data saved to Firestore.');
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error saving clubCounts data to Firestore:', error);
    });
  }

  // Event handler for the button click
  onButtonClick() {
    // Access your clubCounts data from the 'clubCounts$' observable
    this.clubCounts$.subscribe((clubCountsData: ClubData) => {
      // Save the clubCounts data to Firestore
      this.saveClubCountsToFirestore(clubCountsData);
    });
  }
```

However, it just saves an empty array, and a timestamp field.

Comment: `clubData.push({ clubId, clubName: club.name, count });` runs asynchronously because it is in `subscribe`. So `return clubData` returns empty array.

Comment: Thanks @N.F.
Actually, the function getClubCounts() works fine and produces the expected result. 

What I'm having difficulty with is saving the retrieved data in saveClubCountsToFirestore()

Answer (score 0):

Resolution:

Create a variable clubData[] = [];

Then in the service:

```
        const clubData: ClubData[] = []; // remove this line
    Object.entries(clubCounts).forEach(([clubId, count]) => {
      this.firestore.doc(`clubs/${clubId}`).valueChanges().subscribe((club: any) => {
        this.clubData.push({ clubId, clubName: club.name, count });
      });
    });
    
    return this.clubData;
  }),
```

Finally in the function to save to Firestore:

```
    // Save club counts data to Firestore
saveClubCountsToFirestore() {
  const dateSaved = serverTimestamp();
  return this.firestore.collection('revenueReports').add({
    dateSaved,
    clubCountsData: this.clubData as any[], // Use the stored data
  });
}
```

And the records are saved as an array/map as expected.